# What is the standard error behavior when multiple elements share the same id?

Tags: javascript, html, standards

I'm working on automated tests with Selenium for a complex, enterprise-grade web app, and I ran into some problems.

It seems the programmers don't hold standard HTML too high in their priority. Pages aren't compliant at all. My current problem is that several elements share the same `id` value, which, obviously, isn't a good thing. I'm not allowed to change it, and anyways I don't think I would like to.

What happens when many elements have the same id? How do popular browsers handle that? I'm especially asking in the case of `document.getElementById`: which one is returned?

Comment: Why don't you write a small app to try it out? I think to remember, that ff returns the first found element.

Comment: The document will not validate with the w3 validation service, but the actual behavior in the browser has not been defined in the spec, so each browser can behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is something internal to `document.getElementId` that I am not privy to, I would expect it to return the first element it encounters. (See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrTra/)

Although browser behaviours may vary, I believe most will ignore the other entries without reporting an error.

**EDIT**

Found this link: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/getElementById

> When multiple elements share the same
> ID
>
> The behavior of this method when
> more than one element of the specified
> ID exists is not standardized, because
> a document is not allowed to contain
> more than one element with the same
> ID. But for reference, in this
> situation all browsers return the
> first element found.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` returns the first element with the id

tested in FF, IE, Chrome, Safari & Opera